# Triple integral calculation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$
\text { Find the volume of the solid bounded by the surfaces } x=0 \text { and } y^{2}+z^{2}=4 \text { and } x+z=4
$$

The part which I am confused is what are limits of integration over here $x$ goes from $ 0 $ to $4-z$ ; $ y $ goes from $0$ to $ 4 - z^2$ and $ z $ from  $0$ to $z$. Is it correct?

Comment: the last limit should have only numbers at both ends, otherwise the volume would be a variable

Answer (score 3):

We can refer to the $y, z$ plane and the integration boundary is a circle centered in the origin with radius $r=2$.

Then x varies from $0$ to $4-z$.

Comment: Maybe can you write integral representation?

Comment: @mathsstudent $y^{2}+z^{2}=4$ is a cylinder (its axis is the $x$ axis) and the plane $x+z=4$ cuts it from the positive side of $x$ axis.

Comment: @mathsstudent It is probably $\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}\int_0^{4-z}dxdydz$

Comment: Thank you both of you.

Comment: @mathsstudent Or, you can use cylindrical coordinates to obtain $\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{4-r}rdxd\theta dr$

Comment: @vidyarthi answers coming different for both integral

Comment: @vidyarthi In the polar form the term “4-r” should be $4-r\sin \theta$.

Comment: @gimusi Still it is different I tried it already

Comment: @mathsstudent What result do you obtain? (I guess it sould be $16 \pi$).

Comment: @gimusi yes it is same as you mention but  when I tried long expression it gives differnt result

Comment: Could you please show your full work, so that we can help you to find the mistake?

Comment: @mathsstudent yes, in the polar form( cylindrical form) the height is $r\sin\theta$ sorry for that

Comment: @gimusi I tried using symbolab calculator it shows me different result for  first definite integral that vidyarthi suggests. Since first integral is very cumbersome excercise

Comment: @mathsstudent Sorry I see it now but the correct set up in cartesian should be $$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-z^2}}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}\int_0^{4-y}dxdydz$$

Comment: Yup it works now

Comment: @mathsstudent I confirm also that the polar form $$\int_0^2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{4-r \sin \theta}rdxd\theta dr$$ is correct. You should obtain the same result.

Comment: @mathsstudent Anyway by symmetry we can argue that the volume is an half cylinder with area $4\pi$ and  hight 8.

Comment: why limit is from 0 to 4-y?

Comment: @mathsstudent because $x$ is varing form 0 to the plane surface (which is positive over the integration area).